# What are the minimal permissions to open a list item custom display form

Tags: 2013, development, permissions, list-form, item-level-permissions

I'm working on a solution where permissions are added to users in a very customized way.

When I'm creating an item on my list, I break role inheritance (`item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);`).

I need to have a role where members that have no permissions whatsoever are able to see a (custom) display form when given a URL to it.

At first I thought that when I add `ViewListItems` BasePermissions on that item for a user then it would suffice to let user open the display form, however it didn't.

Which other permissions needs a user have (**on Web/List/Item level**) to be able to see the form?

Comment: If an answer was helpful could you remove your question from the SO unanswered list, by marking it as answered, tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered empirically that these permissions are required **on item level but also on Web level** for a user to display a (custom) display form:

```
"ViewListItems", "ViewPages", "ViewVersions"
```

Answer (score 0):

See: https://365csi.nl/toolkit/permissionsplanner.html?l=en

and then hover over the "View Only" column

Maybe you could even trim to "Limited Access" and only add View Items

[image]